# Configure Liferay tomcat on port 443

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want my Liferay portal to be accessible only by https on port 443. By default it is accessible on port 8080. But after changing port in server.xml in tomcat I am unable to access Liferay. I am using Liferay 6.1 CE on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Configure SSL for your tomcat serve please have look into follwoing link

[Liferay Portal SSL Configuration](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/01/liferay-portal-ssl-configuration.html)

Comment: I have created self signed SSL certificate and changed server.xml,it is working fine on windows. But I am facing problem in Ubuntu Server, similar changes are not working here. I want to know any specific changes for Ubuntu or linux?